# can we pass a directory path to Drawable.createfrompath instead of a file path?

Tags: android

can we pass a directory path to Drawable.createfrompath instead of a file path?

Ex:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("aq/img/sample.png");
```

converts the path to a drawable "d". I want to pass a folder path to the same function, say "/aq/img/" and I want convert all images present in that folder into a drawable. Can this be done? and how?

EDIT:
Did this to display a single image in my imageView.

```
 ImageView imgView01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
            File dir = new File("/sdcard/WallpapersHD/");
             File file[]=dir.listFiles();

             for (int i=0;i<file.length;i++) {


                 Drawable d = (Drawable) Drawable.createFromPath(file[i].toString());


                 imgView01.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Now how do I set a delay of say 5 seconds and then set a different image in the imageview?

Comment: How would you expect it to combine all the images together into a single Drawable? One on top of the other, or tiled, etc? I wouldn't expect that to be a framework/OS-supported operation, to be honest, partly because of the number of variations you could imagine. I expect you'll just have to do it explicitly in code.

Comment: after converting each path to a drawable I want to set it into an imageview using "imgView01.setImageDrawable(d);" and then reuse the same imageview and same drawable to other images in the folder. Basically I want to display all images within the folder one after the other.

Comment: Ah, one after another - that's not the same as passing in a folder and getting *one* `Drawable` in one go though, is it? Why not just create a new `Drawable` for each file?

Comment: yep thats what I was trying to ask. Sorry on not being very clear. To create a new Drawable for each file, how do I get the path to each image in that folder?

Comment: So really your question is "How do I find the files in a directory?" - in which case `File.listFiles` may be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot! got it. Now I'm trying to figure out how to implement delay timers so that the images change one after the other. It currently displays only one image. Question edited above..

Answer (score 0):

After do this to start to count 5 seconds

```
long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealTime();
```

put this into a loop:

```
if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() > time + 5000){

        ImageView img01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourNewImg);
        img01.setImageDrawable(d);

}
```

"d" is your Drawable.